# Range update and querying in a 2D matrix

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, segment-tree

I don't have a scenario, but here goes the problem. This is one is just driving me crazy. There is a nxn boolean matrix initially all elements are 0, n <= 10^6 and given as input.
Next there will be up to 10^5 queries. Each query can be either set all elements of column c to 0 or 1, or set all elements of row r to 0 or 1. There can be another type of query, printing the total number of 1's in column c or row r.

I have no idea how to solve this and any help would be appreciated. Obviously a O(n) solution per query is not feasible.

Comment: What needs to be solved here?

Comment: Calculating the total number of 1's in a row or column after possible modification of the matrix

Comment: I fail to see why O(n) per query is not feasible.  Each of those queries seems like an O(n) operation to me.  Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: My friend gave me this problem. He says there is a much elegant and efficient solution. n <= 10^6 and total numbers of queries is up to 10^5. 10^11 loops will take a long time that's why it is not feasible.

Comment: Ah, you mean that you need to do better than that.  I read it that you did not believe it was feasible to obtain an O(n) per query result.

Comment: One thing to note is that for a particular Row/Col Query operation, we require the last Row/Col Set operation and then count the the number of Col/Row set operation between them. The question is then about handle duplicates Row/Col Set operations, I guess

Comment: Sorry for any ambiguity @femtoRgon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of using a number to order the modifications is taken from Dukeling's post.

We will need 2 maps and 4 binary indexed tree (BIT, a.k.a. Fenwick Tree): 1 map and 2 BITs for rows, and 1 map and 2 BITs for columns. Let us call them `m_row`, `f_row[0]`, and `f_row[1]`; `m_col`, `f_col[0]` and `f_col[1]` respectively.

Map may be implemented with array, or tree like structure, or hashing. The 2 maps are used to store the last modification to a row/column. Since there can be at most 10<sup>5</sup> modification, you may use that fact to save space from simple array implementation.

BIT has 2 operations:

- `adjust(value, delta_freq)`, which adjusts the frequency of the `value` by `delta_freq` amount.
- `rsq(from_value, to_value)`, (rsq stands for range sum query) which finds the sum of the all the frequencies from `from_value` to `to_value` inclusive.

Let us declare global variable: `version`

Let us define `numRow` to be the number of rows in the 2D boolean matrix, and `numCol` to be the number of columns in the 2D boolean matrix.

The BITs should have size of at least MAX_QUERY + 1, since it is used to count the number of changes to the rows and columns, which can be as many as the number of queries.

Initialization:

```
version = 1
# Map should return <0, 0> for rows or cols not yet
# directly updated by query
m_row = m_col = empty map
f_row[0] = f_row[1] = f_col[0] = f_col[1] = empty BIT
```

Update algorithm:

```
update(isRow, value, idx):
    if (isRow):
        # Since setting a row/column to a new value will reset
        # everything done to it, we need to erase earlier
        # modification to it.
        # For example, turn on/off on a row a few times, then
        # query some column
        <prevValue, prevVersion> = m_row.get(idx)
        if ( prevVersion > 0 ):
            f_row[prevValue].adjust( prevVersion, -1 )

        m_row.map( idx, <value, version> )
        f_row[value].adjust( version, 1 )
    else:
        <prevValue, prevVersion> = m_col.get(idx)
        if ( prevVersion > 0 ):
            f_col[prevValue].adjust( prevVersion, -1 )

        m_col.map( idx, <value, version> )
        f_col[value].adjust( version, 1 )

    version = version + 1
```

Count algorithm:

```
count(isRow, idx):
    if (isRow):
        # If this is row, we want to find number of reverse modifications
        # done by updating the columns
        <value, row_version> = m_row.get(idx)
        count = f_col[1 - value].rsq(row_version + 1, version)
    else:
        # If this is column, we want to find number of reverse modifications
        # done by updating the rows
        <value, col_version> = m_col.get(idx)
        count = f_row[1 - value].rsq(col_version + 1, version)

    if (isRow):
       if (value == 1):
           return numRow - count
       else:
           return count
    else:
       if (value == 1):
           return numCol - count
       else:
           return count
```

The complexity is logarithmic in worst case for both update and count.

Comment: What are the methods rsq, add and adjust ? Could you add a brief detail about them

Comment: @WayneRooney: Thanks for the comment. There shouldn't be `add`.

Comment: Also what is numRow and numCol?? Is rsq the cumulative sum method ?

Answer (score 1):

Take version just to mean a value that gets auto-incremented for each update.

Store the last version and last update value at each row and column.

Store a list of (versions and counts of zeros and counts of ones) for the rows. The same for the columns. So that's only 2 lists for the entire grid.

When a row is updated, we set its version to the current version and insert into the list for rows the version and `if (oldRowValue == 0) zeroCount = oldZeroCount else zeroCount = oldZeroCount + 1` (so it's not the number of zero's, rather the number of times a value was updated with a zero). Same for oneCount. Same for columns.

If you do a print for a row, we get the row's version and last value, we do a binary search for that version in the column list (first value greater than). Then:

```
if (rowValue == 1)
  target = n*rowValue
           - (latestColZeroCount - colZeroCount)
           + (latestColOneCount - colOneCount)
else
  target = (latestColOneCount - colOneCount)
```

Not too sure whether the above will work.

That's O(1) for update, O(log k) for print, where k is the number of updates.

Comment: In the problem it is clearly mentioned that the author does not want an O(n) per query solution.

Comment: thanks, but isn't it still O(n) to calculate the number of 1's in a row/column? May be this can be solved with a O(logn) or O(log^2 n) with a segment tree or fenwick tree like data structure.

Comment: Ok just for clarification. Let's assume the worst case scenario. Say 50% of the queries are updates and 50% are asking to calculate the total number of 1's.

Comment: I think the list/set should be sorted by value, then version. So if the current row/col is 0, we can binary search for value 1 with newer version.

Comment: @nhahtdh I'm not sure that will fix anything.